# VBA Change date format in textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert into textbox1 a date like "feb-2016" and to memorize in a variable "data" like i insert it.

```
Private Sub importa_buton_Click()
Dim data As Date
Dim luna As String
Dim anul As Integer


data = Analiza_Date.TextBox1.Value
TextBox1.Value = Format(data, "mmm-yyyy")

luna = month(data)
anul = year(data)

msgbox data
msgbox luna
msgbox anul
```

With the code above the output for `msgbox data` is 01.02.2016 and i want to display like input "feb-2016"

Comment: what is dispalyed in `MsgBox` when you try `Msgbox Format(data, "mmm-yyyy")`, you are converting to your desired format in `TextBox1.Value = Format(data, "mmm-yyyy")` , but not when displaying in `MsgBox`

Comment: It's ok with `msgbox` but i want to use also the `data` variable further

Comment: do you want `data` to be in a format of `"mmm-yyyyy"` ? a String ?

Comment: You can't save the date format in a `Date` variable. One way could be to define `Dim data as String` instead of `Date`, or to build a user type or a class to save the date format in addition to the date value.

Comment: At the end i want 3 variables: `"data" as date`, `"luna" as string` and `"anul" as integer`

Comment: @Marius see answer below to store these variables as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to save:

`data As Date` , `luna As String` and `anul As Integer`

```
Private Sub importa_buton_Click()

Dim data As Date
Dim luna As String
Dim anul As Integer

data = Analiza_Date.TextBox1.value
TextBox1.value = Format(data, "mmm-yyyy")

luna = Format(data, "mmm")
anul = Year(data)

MsgBox luna & "-" & anul
MsgBox luna
MsgBox anul

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a string with the two functions `MonthName` and `Year` like this

```
Dim str As String
str = MonthName(date, TRUE) & "-" & Year(date)
```

where `date` is your date. If the second argument in `MonthName` is `TRUE` then the abbreviation and not the full month name is returned.